# print in awk is removing the spaces while printing

Tags: unix, awk, wc

I am trying to print the values with awk , but it is modifying the result by removing the spaces in between fields.
I am not getting how to maintain the spaces between fields.

```
echo "First Names       City     Names     ES"|awk '{$1=$2=$NF="";print $0}'|wc -c
```

the above statement while printing is removing the spaces between "City" and "Names" as a result the value of wc -c is getting impacted.

Please suggest how to maintain the spaces.
My goal is to validate the length of the "City  Names" value

I have one more doubt about wc -c output , it always gives 1+ to actual value i.e. if length is 11 it is giving 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please suggest how to maintain the spaces.

Use a field separator:

```
$ echo "First Names       City     Names     ES"|awk -F'[ ]' '{$1=$2=$NF="";print $0}'
        City     Names
```

> I have one more doubt about wc -c output , it always gives 1+ to
>   actual value

That's because of the newline.  Instead of `echo`, you can say `echo -n` so as to disable the trailing newline.

```
$ echo | wc -c
1
$ echo -n | wc -c
0
```